# Metadata Api: Unable to update to active values for picklist in record type

Tags: metadata-api, record-type

I am trying to update the record type to move the picklist values to the 'active values' . I am using the metadata api. Below is my code where Scope_Of_Services_Tasks__c is the name of object , Meeting_Type__c is the field name and Project_Management is the name of the Record type :-

```
MetadataService.RecordType rt = new MetadataService.RecordType();
rt.active = true;
rt.fullName = 'Project_Management';
rt.label = 'Project Management';
MetadataService.PicklistValue pv = new MetadataService.PicklistValue();
pv.fullName = 'test123';

MetadataService.RecordTypePicklistValue ohmVersions = new MetadataService.RecordTypePicklistValue();
ohmVersions.Picklist = 'Meeting_Type__c';
ohmVersions.values = new MetadataService.PicklistValue[] { pv };
rt.PicklistValues = new MetadataService.RecordTypePicklistValue[] { ohmVersions };


return handleSaveResults(
    service.updateMetadata(
        new MetadataService.Metadata[] { rt })[0]);
```

The code is giving this error :- "Web service callout failed: WebService returned a SOAP Fault: '' is not valid for type xsd:boolean, should be '0', '1', 'true' or 'false' faultcode=soapenv:Client faultactor="

PLease help me out as this is very urgent and I am trying since more than 2 days. Thanks

Update:- pv.fullName = 'test123'; here 'test123' is the picklist value that need to be moved to the active values in the record type picklist.

Comment: does :     `pv.default_x = false;` help?

Comment: Nope...Still same error

Comment: Do you read the RecordType first before updating it? Although my use of the wrapper is for updating PicklistValues on CustomField, I read the CustomField first before doing the update. Otherwise, you'll smash whatever was there beforehand.

Comment: Actually this is the only I am doing that I have posted

Comment: I can only say that when I used the metadata API to update a picklist, I first used readData to fetch the metadata object, updated in apex the various objects deserialized by the readData and then used update as you show above.  This ensures that all fields are set to values as they were in SFDC and one only changes the object.field values as needed. I carefully looked at the example code in the apex wrapper to the metadata api package

Comment: Please can you give me some code examples of yours ? That would be great. Thanks

Comment: @crop1645  Thank you sooooooo.... much. Your suggestion of 'reading the record type' and did the trick. But data is smashed now .lol

Answer (score 1):

Here is your issue

I'm presuming you are using the Apex wrapper to the metadata API [as found here](https://github.com/financialforcedev/apex-mdapi)

1. In order to use the `service.updateMetadata(..)` method, you first need to use the `readMetaData(..)` method for the metadata object you intend to update.  In your case, this is the `MetadataService.RecordType`
2. The Apex Metadata API wrapper will take the JSON response from the Metadata API and deserialize into the various `MetadataService` wrapper classes that represent the `MetaDataService.RecordType` and its child object collections
3. All of the wrapper class fields will be properly populated to mirror what is in SFDC. Hence, all of the Boolean fields will have values.
4. You then need to modify the datastructure, taking care not to smash lists of existing values to add the new picklist item to an existing recordType's picklist of interest.
5. Finally, you can do the `updateMetaData(..)`

A close relevant example provided in class `MetadataServiceExamples` is method `updatePicklist()` where you can see the `readMetaData(..)` call preceding the `updateMetadata()` call.

Answer (score 0):

> `Web service callout failed: WebService returned a SOAP Fault: '' is not valid for type xsd:boolean, should be '0', '1', 'true' or 'false' faultcode=soapenv:Client faultactor=`

means that you have a **required** Boolean set as `null`.  That Boolean needs to be either `true` or `false`.